# Нужна помощь в создании простой функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы

Всем привет.
Изучаю Javascript.
Возникла сложность в создании простой функции.
Суть задания:

> Сделайте функцию delElem, которая параметрами будет принимать значение
> и массив и удалять из массива все элементы с таким значением.

Мой код.

```
function delElem(param1, param2) {

    let arr = [];
    for (elem of param2) {
        if (elem === param1) {
            continue;// по задумке равные элементы пропускаем и не складываем в новый массив; 
        }
        else {
            arr.push(elem);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(delElem(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: и в чём проблема? всё работает.

Comment: Функция не работает

Comment: @Mitya, почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: Точно работает))))

Comment: Ну значит решили. Расходимся)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
const delElem = (val, arr) => arr.filter(elem => elem !== val);

console.log(delElem(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```